# Right way to add HTML bloginfo name using a filter

Tags: filters, bloginfo

I would like to style parts of bloginfo name from a filter. The only thing I want to do is change the site-title of the blog to include HTML so that I can do individual font-settings on part of the name.

I'm using the twentyeleven and wonder how I can do this in a filter.

When I add a filter for bloginfo and modify the name, it gets modified also in the title of the page and in the title attribute of the A element. I would only like to modify the bloginfo['name'] that is shown *inside* the A element.

Is there someway possible to check the context you are in while the filter callback is called for more fine grained control of the output?

Answer (score 2):

You can't check the context while the filter callback is called, because the element is already in the frontend. There are 3 solutions though:

## 1. jQuery

Search for the element and add html to the places in the name.

## 2. PHP in element

Get the bloginfo('name'); in the element and change it on that place using PHP.

## 3. PHP in header

Add HTML to your bloginfo('name') and strip it back out in de header.php file where the title is generated using the strip_tags() function:

```
strip_tags(get_bloginfo('name'));
```

I'd go with the 3rd option, since it's the fastest method without changing to much.